# Checking for duplicate strings and discarding them?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have two files I have created that by parsing other files and removing the relevant information. One of the files has lines that look like this:

```
Ahmed,Safdar:D433:181:20.40:30.00
Gonzales,Carlos:D433:7732:18.00:24.00
Thanhachammet,Chendrit:D500:5833:8.40:12.10
Bush,G:D500:8343:13.00:19.00
```

The other one:

```
343#2#8#011104
1958#2#9#011204
181##16#012404
773##4#012404
```

I want to check if the 3rd field of the colon separated lines matches the first field of the pound sign separated lines. If it does I want to generate a list of which lines matched. I'm kind of stuck on how to do this. This is what I tried: t

```
temp=$(mktemp)
dept=$(cut -d: -f3 "$tempDept")
pay=$(cut -d# -f1 "$tempPay")
if echo "$dept" | grep -w "$pay"; then
        cat "$dept" >> "$temp"
        cat "$pay" >> "$temp"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`, you could say:

```
awk -F'[:#]' 'FNR==NR {_[$1];next} $3 in _' pound_separated_file colon_separated_file
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
Ahmed,Safdar:D433:181:20.40:30.00
```

Comment: But thats the same line as above...?

Comment: @Whoppa Your question says: `I want to check if the 3rd field of the colon separated lines matches the first field of the pound sign separated lines. If it does I want to generate a list of which lines matched.`.  It'd help if you added the expected output.

Comment: I guess you're right thats my fault I'm an idiot. If they match I want to multiply 4th field from the colon line with the second field from the pound line. Then redirect it to a file. Is there a way I could put your awk in an if statement? Something like if awk; then "$var" = 4th : field * 2nd # field | bc; var >> "$file"; fi

Comment: @Whoppa And what would be the multiplication factor when the second field in the pound line doesn't contain any value?

Comment: I have multiple occurrences of the same ID (first field of pound line) in multiples lines. For Ahmed Safdar for example I also have: 181#96#38#010304, 181#12##040404, 181#3##060304

Comment: Some IDs (first field pound line) have multiple lines and some dont. If theyre are repeats I want to sum them in the end.

Comment: @Whoppa Please update your question rather than supplying this information in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use `join`.

```
$ cat 1
Ahmed,Safdar:D433:181:20.40:30.00
Gonzales,Carlos:D433:7732:18.00:24.00
Thanhachammet,Chendrit:D500:5833:8.40:12.10
Bush,G:D500:8343:13.00:19.00

$ cat 2
343#2#8#011104
1958#2#9#011204
181##16#012404
773##4#012404

$ sort -t: -k3 1 > 1a

$ sed 's/#/:/g' 2 | sort -t: -k 1 > 2a

$ cat 1a
Ahmed,Safdar:D433:181:20.40:30.00
Thanhachammet,Chendrit:D500:5833:8.40:12.10
Gonzales,Carlos:D433:7732:18.00:24.00
Bush,G:D500:8343:13.00:19.00

$ cat 2a
181::16:012404
1958:2:9:011204
343:2:8:011104
773::4:012404

$ join -t: -1 3 -2 1 1a 2a
181:Ahmed,Safdar:D433:20.40:30.00::16:012404
```

Comment: in bash, you don't have to create temp files for the sorted files, you use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution): `join -t: -1 3 -2 1 <(sort -t: -k3 file1) <(sed 's/#/:/g' file2 | sort -t: -k 1)`